# How I can cross-build my app to run in windows XP 32bit from linux using the openSSl libray that I've just built?

Tags: linux, windows, openssl, mingw32

I need to make a legacy app for windows XP (like it or not I am in a position that I have no other choice) that consumes a single http call. But that call is upon TLS 1.2 and I expect in the future TLS 1.3 so I've got to build my app with my own SSL.

Therefore, in my linux machine I've setup a windows XP Vm and mingw:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 wine64
sudo apt-get install g++-mingw-w64-i686 g++-mingw-w64-i686
```

And I build the openssl:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
cd ./openssl-1.1.1q
./config enable-tls1_3 enable-tls1_2 no-asm no-async no-dso no-engine --prefix=./config enable-tls1_3 enable-tls1_2 no-asm no-async no-dso no-engine --prefix=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
make -j 16
```

And in `./openssl-1.1.1q` I have 2 .so files:

```
libcrypto.so.1.1
libssl.so.1.1
```

Also so far I've made a following project:

```
| my_win_app
| - main.cpp
| - openssl-1.1.1q
| -- libcrypto.so
| -- libssl.so
```

The `main.cpp` is the following:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "4116"
#define FAIL    -1

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

SOCKET OpenConnection(char* hostname, int port)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo* ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("google.com", "449", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    ptr = result;
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    return ConnectSocket;
}


SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    const SSL_METHOD* method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}


void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509* cert;
    char* line;
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if (cert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        //free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        //free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[1024];
    char acClientRequest[1024] = { 0 };

    SSL_library_init();
    char* hostname = "google.com";
    char* portnum = "449";

    SSL_CTX* ctx = InitCTX();
    int server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */


    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    } else {
        const char* cpRequestMessage = "";

        printf("\n\nConnected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
       
        /* get any certs */
        ShowCerts(ssl);   
        /* encrypt & send message */
        SSL_write(ssl, acClientRequest, strlen(acClientRequest));  

        /* get reply & decrypt */
        int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); 

        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        /* release connection state */
        SSL_free(ssl);       
    }

    /* close socket */
    closesocket(server);   
    /* release context */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        
    return 0;
}
```

And what attempts to do is to fetch the google's frontpage via http 1.1 ontop of openssl using winsock. The issue is that openssl is unable to be found:

```
$ LANG=C i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.cpp ./openssl-1.1.1q/libssl.so ./openssl-1.1.1q/libcrypto.so -o  main.exe -lws2_32 -lopenssl
main.cpp:9:10: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What I want is to link my main.cpp during cross-compilation with the openssl I've just built. But I am unable to do so. Any ideas why?

### Attempt 2

I re-built my openSSL with:

```
cd ./openssl-1.1.1q
make clean
./Configure enable-tls1_3 no-asm no-async no-dso no-engine no-shared --cross-compile-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --prefix=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc mingw

make -j16
```

And I re-tried to rebuild my application:

```
$ LANG=C i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -lws2_32 -Iopenssl-1.1.1q/include -o main.exe
main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: openssl/applink.c: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/applink.c>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Still fails to build. As I can see I cannot build the file applink.c. Furthermore I renamed `main.cpp` into `main.c`

Comment: **Your problem (now) is compilation not linking.** To compile code using (a particular) OpenSSL with gcc (and most other compilers) you must specify the directory for the include files with `-I` (upper eye) -- given your file layout you probably want `-Iopenssl-1.1.1q/include`. However, since you didn't specify a MINGW target to `./config` I expect this build won't actually run. At the same time you fix that, you could consider adding `no-shared` -- if you only have one app, static linking is simpler than managing the multiple library files.

Comment: Also I don't see any actual C++ in your code so you should either use -xc or rename it .c to compile as C. OpenSSL is (all) C and if you do need to call it from C++ you must put the #include-d declarations for it, plus applink.c, inside `extern "C" { ... }`. I don't _think_ the mingw-ified windows headers need this, but check to be sure. Plus do you really want `google.com 449`? There's no server there, SSL/HTTPS or otherwise. The standard and nearly universal HTTPS port is 443.

Comment: I re-tried to do it but still fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't done `make install` in my case it will install the files into `openssl-1.1.1q/C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL/include/openssl` therefore you'll need to compile it like this:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -lws2_32 -I"openssl-1.1.1q/C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL/include" -o main.exe
```

When crossbuilding openssl1.1.0g look for `C:` folder inside the directory you've downloaded the openssl library. In your case it is the `./openssl-1.1.1q`